# Android Check Box in the Listview un expected behavior

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I have Custom listview which consist of the check box and the Textview. For some reasons I can not use the ListActivity. Well its pretty easy to use the listview but I do not know why Check box is behaving differently .

First let me give you a idea what I am doing , below is the part of my Adapter

```
 private static class ViewHolder { //My View Hold
    TextView tvParentGradeName;
    CheckBox cbParentClassesOfGrades;

}
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        final ClassModelInfo user = getItem(position);


        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
            // If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceLayout, parent, false);

            viewHolder.tvParentGradeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvParentGradeName);
            viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbParentClassesOfGrades);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades.setChecked(false);
            //Following list consist of ids of items whoes check box are checked alredy 
            if(selectedItemsList!= null && selectedItemsList.size()>0){
                for(int i = 0 ; i<selectedItemsList.size();i++){
                if(user.getClassID().matches(""+selectedItemsList.get(i))){
                    viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades.setChecked(true);
                }
                }

            }

            viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    listClass.get(getPosition).setSetSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
//                    if(callback!=null)
//                    callback.checkBoxChecked();
                    if (isChecked) {


                        selectedItemsList.add(Integer.parseInt(user.getClassID()));

                    } else {
//                            selectedItemsList.remove(classsLevelClickedItems.getId());
                        Iterator<Integer> myItr = selectedItemsList.iterator();

                        while (myItr.hasNext()) {
                            Integer id = myItr.next();
                            System.out.println("Next name is: " + id);
                            if (id == Integer.parseInt(user.getClassID())) {
                                myItr.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.tvParentGradeName, viewHolder.tvParentGradeName);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.cbParentClassesOfGrades, viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades.setTag(position); // This line is important.


            viewHolder.tvParentGradeName.setText(user.getClassName()+" ("+gradeDictionary.get(Integer.parseInt(user.getGradeID()))+")");

            viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades.setChecked(user.isSetSelected());


        return convertView;

    }
```

**Now if I remove the following lines, the check box behavior gets strange , for example if I check the 4th check box , and start scrolling the listview I would see that the check box which are coming are already checked , I do not know what is such behavior **

> viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades.setTag(position); // This line is important.
>   viewHolder.tvParentGradeName.setText(user.getClassName()+" >("+gradeDictionary.get(Integer.parseInt(user.getGradeID()))+")");
>   viewHolder.cbParentClassesOfGrades.setChecked(user.isSetSelected());

**So basically As I have mentioned my biggest problem above** below are some questions

1) how to make consistent listview with a check box , I mean listview should remember exactly which check box was clicked

2) how can I make the click listener on whole row of listview ,this will help the user to click on the item and to mark the check box (check and un check) so user will no need to check the checkbox specifically.

Please tell me how can I improve this ? this is taking my days.

> **Note:** I have searched that problem alot and in my code the line with a comment  is one which I copied from net.

Comment: that is not a strange behaviour. It is the intended behaviour as rows are reused in listview. To solve this you have to save the checked position and when inflating rows check for the position and proceed accordingly

Comment: can you show me the way of doing that

Comment: http://techlovejump.com/android-listview-with-checkbox/. Check this link. Though it only shows half of the work. on Click of check box you have to save that position in a model class

Comment: i got your point but can you tell me how can I get the ids of items , whoes check box is clicked, actually i have a button in a activity , when user will click , it will call a webservice and that needs a array of ids , of those items which are clicked (checked)

Comment: why you need checkbox id? Just save that position in your modal class

Comment: no I didnt said I need check box id , i need the ids of items, let say , there is a list of students , if check box is checked I need the roll nums of all checked student on a button clicked in the activity

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep track of checked and unchecked positions and mark it check in your adopter. As in list view it is desired behavior. You have to handle it in code.
Create an array for the list items, when a checkbox is clicked, update the array for that position and in adapter mark check/uncheck with the respective value of the array.

```
 public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo>  {

private List<ApplicationInfo> appInfoList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private PackageManager pm;
ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;
private Context ctx;
int[] visiblePosArray;
private volatile int positionCheck; 

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> myList) {
    super(context, NO_SELECTION);
    appInfoList = myList;
    ctx=context;
    mInflater =     (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    pm = context.getPackageManager();

    positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(myList.size());
    for(int i =0;i<myList.size();i++){
        positionArray.add(false);
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return appInfoList.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;

    if(row==null){
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.testlayout, null); 
        //  visiblePosArray[position%visiblePosArray.length]=position;
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.appIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.ckbox =(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    }

    holder.ckbox.setFocusable(false);
    holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(appInfoList.get(position).loadIcon(pm));
    holder.ckbox.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
    holder.ckbox.setText(appInfoList.get(position).loadLabel(pm));
    holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked ){
            System.out.println(position+"--- :)");
                positionArray.set(position, true);

            }else
                positionArray.set(position, false);
        }
    });

    return row;
}
static class Holder
{
    ImageView appIcon;
    CheckBox ckbox;

}
}
```

Comment: great and what if i have a button in the Activity and then I have to get all the items ids, whoes check box are checked, , I have that button in the activity out side adpater

Comment: you can have a method in your adapter which can give all that ids or whatever check information is required. and you can call that method from your activity

Comment: what do you mean by that ca you please demonstrate, I am dumb in android